# How to set "content" on an :after element inline with the text

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element, css-content

I have an li-tag in my menu:

```
nav ul li ul.firstmenu li.secondtothree{
float: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid #DCDCDA;
padding:3px;
text-transform:none;
}
```

Then I want to add ">" after the menupoints, so that it looks like "Home  >"  or  "Article >".

This is my :after:

```
nav ul li ul.firstmenu li.secondtothree:after{
    content: ">";
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: right;
    display: inline-block;
    width:100%;
    right:0px;
}
```

But the ">" is always in the next row. Is it possible to set it directly in the line after the menupoint?

Comment: looks like it's because of `width:100%`, you should set `margin` to put some space between the main text and the `:after`'s content.

Comment: Set the margin=0 has no effect unfortunately

Comment: normally you don't need `width:100%`, and then you may need `margin` to put some space between the main text and the content, otherwise they will be close to each other, hence bad looking. I did not mean you had to use `margin` to solve your problem, it's just needed to make it better looking.

Answer (score 1):

Generated content is already placed inline by default. You don't need any of these properties:

```
text-align: right;
display: inline-block;
width:100%;
right:0px;
```

Comment: And do you have a hint what I can do to have the "content" where it should be?

Comment: @Zwen2012: What do you mean "where it should be"? Since you're using `:after` the content should be placed directly after the text - that's exactly where it should be (once you remove all the unnecessary properties anyway).

Comment: it is in the next line! Like this-> "Home <br> >" but it should be "Home >"